# What is the reason of the particular range of the last 4K block of memory selection in Apple II

Tags: apple-ii, memory-layout

Following my previous question on [Identifying the functionality of the memory select in Apple II](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17906/identifying-the-functionalinty-of-the-memory-select-ic-in-apple-ii) and now that I know that the memory select device is simply an interconnection block. Searching for more, I found the Apple II red book where the memory select is explained with the following figure:

[image]

So I represent the interconnection scheme as I got it. For 16K/16K/16k:

[image]

For 16K/4K/4K:

[image]

Now the question is: why the last 4K block is (6000 - EFFF) and not (8000 - 8FFF)?

Is it related to RAM mirroring, bank-switched ROM or anything else?

Comment: It probably is a typo.  However, it is worth noting that BASIC in the Apple **1** needed RAM in the `$E000-$EFFF` address range.

Comment: @DrSheldon it seems it is a typo but check this: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/6020/18338

Comment: To clarify my comment: It's plausible that while Woz was developing the Apple II, he used the BASIC from the Apple 1.  That would require having RAM in the `$E000-$EFFF` address range.  Once the II had its own BASIC, such a mapping would no longer be necessary.  It would also explain why there were jumpers for address ranges that were apparently never used.

Comment: @DrSheldon thank you it is clear now. I misunderstood your first comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually my book has `$8000-$8FFF` for pin 7 (but it's a German translation).

And it's also `$8000-$8FFF` in the Apple II Reference manual on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/apple-ii-ref-manual/page/n79/mode/2up), p. 71.

And it's also `$8000-$8FFF` in the Apple II red book on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/Apple_II_Redbook/page/n135/mode/2up), p. 133, though you can see that there is a hand-drawn correction in it.

So, a mistake that was later corrected? Can you give a link to the Apple II red book where you found it?

Comment: Link to where I found it: http://apple2online.com/web_documents/apple_ii_redbook_30th_anniversary_ed.pdf  page 133(140).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not near my Red Book at the moment, but a quick look at the schematics seems to support (*1) your assumption of Block 7 being $8000-$8FFF.

The fine details of how it's decoded are rather complex. You may want to take a look at how thee 139's on position E2/F2 are connected to the address lines (A12..15), and especially how E2 is enabled, as well as note that what is A6 on a 16 Ki RAM (4116) is /CS on a 4 Ki type (4096).

---

*1 - Haven't drawn up the full table, so no guarantee here.

Comment: What advantage would there be with having a decode for 0x8000-0x8FFF rather than selecting the top 4K bank for all addresses 0x8000-0xBFFF?  Even if one wanted to use an expansion board to push beyond 36K, I would think a bank of 16K DRAM chips would be cheaper than an expansion board that used 4K DRAM chips.

Comment: @supercat Keep in mind, the design for the Apple II was made at a time when 4 Ki Chips were available and 16 Ki only announced recently. Also, what you want can simply be done by using the 16/16/16 block for CAS. But that would be a hack, disabling ecpansion for that area on interface cards.

Comment: My question was why Apple bothered generating that chip select, when omitting it would have made the circuitry simpler (looking at the schematic, I think there are a couple of gates whose purpose is to tweak the inputs to a 74LS139 so it yields the proper output, though I don't quite understand how the circuit is supposed to work).  Using a 74LS138 to yield eight consecutive outputs and just using the first six would seem like it would have been simpler.

Comment: @supercat Keep in mind, it handles video access as well, the decoding comes almost for free. I not really sure that Woz can be accused of wasting gates, or would you think so?

Comment: Woz was brilliant, but that doesn't mean his design was perfect.  If there was a need to have a decode for the exact region $8000-$9FFF, his circuit is probably a good way of getting that, but the circuit could have been simpler if pins 7-8 had simply been connected on the motherboard in the places that generate CAS for 4K DRAM chips, but pin 7 was connected to pins 1-6 where those are all tied together.